# default arguments not being recognized in custom function using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, quasiquotes

Take this function `foo()`. I want it to have a default argument of `cyl` because that's the name of the field it will usually process.

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <- function(x = cyl){
    case_when(
        x == 6 ~ TRUE,
        x == 8 ~ FALSE,
        x == 4 ~ NA
    )
}

# works: 
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cyl_refactor = foo(cyl)) %>% 
    select(cyl, cyl_refactor)
```

But I am surprised that the function will not work unless I explicitly supply the default argument. See failing code below

```
# fails:
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cyl_refactor = foo()) %>% 
    select(cyl, cyl_refactor)
```

`` Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cyl_refactor`. ℹ `cyl_refactor = foo()`. x object 'cyl' not found ``

It seems that default arguments are only processed when there is also a data parameter as below.

```
foo2 <- function(data, x = cyl){
    data %>% 
        mutate(cyl_refactor = case_when(
        {{x}} == 6 ~ TRUE,
        {{x}} == 8 ~ FALSE,
        {{x}} == 4 ~ NA
    ))
}

mtcars %>% 
    foo2() %>% 
    select(cyl, cyl_refactor)
```

I am sure there is some gap in my knowledge of quasiquotation, but I would like to understand how to use a default argument in `foo()`.

Comment: This is obviously just example code, is there a way to supply foo() with a default argument? do I need to use quoted column names, and if so can quoted column names be processed by case_when()?

Comment: In my real use case it would be better to avoid a data parameter

Comment: So when I try the sym() method I am getting an error: Only strings can be converted to symbols

retain_92dv2 <- function(gns_date = 'qbcommerce_gns_date', cancel_date = 'qbcommerce_cancel_date', duration = 92){
 gns_date <- sym(gns_date)
 cancel_date <- sym(cancel_date)
 dplyr::case_when(
  Sys.Date() - !!gns_date <= duration ~ NA, # unbaked
  Sys.Date() - !!gns_date > duration & is.na(!!cancel_date) ~ TRUE, # baked + no cancel = retained
  !!cancel_date - !!gns_date > duration ~ TRUE,
  !!cancel_date - !!gns_date <= duration ~ FALSE,
  TRUE ~ NA
 )
}

Comment: Is this the idea? To pass quoted arguments and then use arg <- sym(arg) followed by !!arg in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this with `missing` and `cur_data_all`

```
foo <- function(x = cyl){
   if(missing(x)) x <- cur_data_all()[["cyl"]]
   
    case_when(
        x == 6 ~ TRUE,
        x == 8 ~ FALSE,
        x == 4 ~ NA
    )
}
```

-testing

```
> out1 <- mtcars %>% 
+     mutate(cyl_refactor = foo(cyl)) %>% 
+     select(cyl, cyl_refactor)
> out2 <- mtcars %>% 
+     mutate(cyl_refactor = foo()) %>% 
+     select(cyl, cyl_refactor)
> 
> identical(out1, out2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one that will "work" though I woudn't recommend it

```
foo <- function(x = cyl){
  x <- enquo(x)
  eval.parent(rlang::quo_squash(rlang::quo(case_when(
    !!x == 6 ~ TRUE,
    !!x == 8 ~ FALSE,
    !!x == 4 ~ NA
  ))))
}

# Both run without error
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl_refactor = foo(cyl)) %>% 
  select(cyl, cyl_refactor)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl_refactor = foo()) %>% 
  select(cyl, cyl_refactor)
```

The problem is that in order for `case_when` to work, you can't just pass in a column name without also passing in the data. In order to "find" the data in this case, I've used `eval.parent()` to go up the call chain to try to find the `cyl` variable.

It's better to make proper functions where you pass in the input data directly (rather than variable names they need to look up themselves).

Comment: so it sounds like using case_when() in a custom function without a data parameter is going to be problematic for default arguments that it can't "find"

Comment: @Joe It's a problem for any function when you won't pass the data directly as a parameter. Nothing special about `case_when`. If the function has a default parameter that's a variable name, rather than an actual value, it's a problem if that variable isn't defined in the function and only exists in a calling environment. That goes in conflict with the normal behavior of R to look up variables using lexical scoping.